# How to get the list of Regions in the RegionManager in PRISM?

Tags: c#, mvvm, c#-4.0, prism, prism-4

I'v got the following code :

> public class MyModule: IModule
>       {
>           private IRegionManager mRegionManager { get; set; }
>
> ```
>     public CMBaseTable(IRegionManager regMan)
>     {
>         mRegionManager = regMan;
>     }
>
>     public void Initialize()
>     {
>         mRegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion",typeof(MyView));
>         var vs = mRegionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Views;//<--- I get an exception here
>     }
> }
> ```

In the line

> var vs = mRegionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Views;

I'll get an exception that says:
KeyNotFoundException : "The region manager does not contain the MainRegion region."

But I'm sure that MainRegin is defined and other modules have added views in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always take a look into the [source](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/52595#1024743).
RegionCollection implements IEnumarable so you can iterate over the collection or you can
simply use the provided function `public bool ContainsRegionWithName(string regionName)`.

Comment: Thanks ba__friend , after digging the source ,found the answer !! 
The shell must be created before iterating throw mRegionManager.Regions[].

Comment: Hi Ehsan, what do you mean that the shell must be created before iterating through RegionManager regions?